# How to bind a MouseDoubleClick-Event to a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Hi i would like to use a MouseDoubleClick Event to my DataGridTemplateColumn, for the Function- and Processinterface-Row under the H.Column.

but there is no MouseDoubleClick-Event for DataGridTemplateColumn.
can anyone help!

this is my Code:

```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="" Header="H." Width="50">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value="E">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value="Function">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value= "Processinterface">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value="AND">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value="OR">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ObjectType}" Value="XOR">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Button Name="btnTable" Visibility="Hidden" Height="20" Width="25" Click="Button_Table_Click">
                                    <Image Height="16" Source="" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then add in code behind file

`private void dgAcctSearch_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
          //add your logic here
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGrid MouseDoubleClick="dataGridLog_MouseDoubleClick" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dateColumn" Header="Date" Width="80" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="dateColumnTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=DateSent, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" Width="80" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DateSent, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}, Converter={x:Reference Name=DateConverter}, ConverterParameter=>3}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="dateColumnTextBlock" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="priorityColumn" Header="Priority" Width="80" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="priorityColumnTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Priority}" Width="80" />
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Priority}" Value="Urgent">
                                <Setter TargetName="priorityColumnTextBlock" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="titleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=Fault}" Header="Title" Width="270" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is essentially my daragrid. I've shown this to demonstrate that it does have the `MouseDoubleClick`. Also, showing how to use triggers on templates.

Answer (score 0):

write like this

```
<my:DataGrid 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            Margin="22,263,0,0" 
            Name="dgAcctSearch"  
            xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit" 
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            CanUserResizeRows="False" 
            CanUserSortColumns="True" 
            SelectionMode="Extended" 
            SelectionUnit="Cell" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Width="783" 
            Height="331" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            MouseDoubleClick="dgAcctSearch_MouseDoubleClick" 
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"  
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
            CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
            AllowDrop="False"
            Background="WhiteSmoke"
            GridLinesVisibility="All"
            />
```